# Consistency Level of Constraints

Tags: constraint-programming, cp-optimizer

Recently I started using CP and translated my first MIP model into a CP model with the IBM CP Optimizer. Lately I was confronted with a question I could not answer:

"What is the consistency level (e.g. bound consistent or domain consistent) applied to the constraints of the model?"

My Questions:

- What exactly is the consistency level of the constraints of the
  model?
- How can I find out about the consistency level of the
  constraints?
- For which reason would you want to let the reader know about the consistency level? or: Why would the reader be interested?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=2dad28ca-c011-493c-aeaf-27494b0c3e20&CommunityKey=ab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7&tab=digestviewer#bm2dad28ca-c011-493c-aeaf-27494b0c3e20.

Comment: I will try to summarize what I (think to) know so far: The consistency level influences how propagation works. A high consistency level will increase domain reduction, therefore it might take longer to find any solutions and vice versa (due to the duration of the propagation process). I would be glad about any additions made, but this is something I can live with for now.